# Creating a Request body for Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I need to make a request body looking like this:

```
{
  "accepted" : [
    {
      "deposit" : 2000,
      "name" : "Tuxedo",
      "rent" : 100,
      "id" : 3,
      "favourited_by" : [

      ],
      "tag_id" : 21,
      "status" : "unknown",
      "image_url" : "https:\/\/www.moss.co.uk\/images\/extralarge\/965549415_01.jpg",
      "addresses" : [

      ]
    },
    {
      "deposit" : 3000,
      "name" : "ps4",
      "rent" : 50,
      "id" : 2,
      "favourited_by" : [

      ],
      "tag_id" : 16,
      "status" : "unknown",
      "image_url" : "http:\/\/www.spokeslabs.com\/jstone\/ps4_images\/ps4-hrdware-large18.jpg",
      "addresses" : [

      ]
    },
    {
      "deposit" : 1000,
      "name" : "Electric drill",
      "rent" : 100,
      "id" : 1,
      "favourited_by" : [

      ],
      "tag_id" : 11,
      "status" : "unknown",
      "image_url" : "https:\/\/static.independent.co.uk\/s3fs-public\/styles\/story_medium\/public\/thumbnails\/image\/2016\/06\/20\/12\/ryobi-rpd800-k-percussion-d.jpg",
      "addresses" : [

      ]
    }
  ],
  "rejected" : [

  ],
  "address" : 
    {
      "city" : "Hong Kong",
      "lng" : "114.162699999745",
      "country" : "Hong Kong",
      "street" : "Barker Road",
      "id" : "0",
      "label" : "Home",
      "lat" : "22.269837686727"
    }
}
```

Unfortunantly I'm sending this:

```
{
  "accepted" : [
    {
      "deposit" : 2000,
      "name" : "Tuxedo",
      "rent" : 100,
      "id" : 3,
      "favourited_by" : [

      ],
      "tag_id" : 21,
      "status" : "unknown",
      "image_url" : "https:\/\/www.moss.co.uk\/images\/extralarge\/965549415_01.jpg",
      "addresses" : [

      ]
    },
    {
      "deposit" : 3000,
      "name" : "ps4",
      "rent" : 50,
      "id" : 2,
      "favourited_by" : [

      ],
      "tag_id" : 16,
      "status" : "unknown",
      "image_url" : "http:\/\/www.spokeslabs.com\/jstone\/ps4_images\/ps4-hrdware-large18.jpg",
      "addresses" : [

      ]
    },
    {
      "deposit" : 1000,
      "name" : "Electric drill",
      "rent" : 100,
      "id" : 1,
      "favourited_by" : [

      ],
      "tag_id" : 11,
      "status" : "unknown",
      "image_url" : "https:\/\/static.independent.co.uk\/s3fs-public\/styles\/story_medium\/public\/thumbnails\/image\/2016\/06\/20\/12\/ryobi-rpd800-k-percussion-d.jpg",
      "addresses" : [

      ]
    }
  ],
  "rejected" : [

  ],
  "address" : [
    {
      "city" : "Hong Kong",
      "lng" : "114.162699999745",
      "country" : "Hong Kong",
      "street" : "Barker Road",
      "id" : "0",
      "label" : "Home",
      "lat" : "22.269837686727"
    }
  ]
}
```

The difference is in the last section of the JSON. What I'm sending contains an array of addresses but I want to be sending just contains one address object.

This request body gets created the following way:

```
    var parameters = [String:[AnyObject]]()
    parameters["rejected"] = rejectedItemsArray as [AnyObject]
    parameters["accepted"] = acceptedItemsArray as [AnyObject]
    parameters["address"] = addressArray as [AnyObject]

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
    request.setValue(self.token!, forHTTPHeaderField: Constant.tokenUserDefaultsKey)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    do {
        let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: .PrettyPrinted)
        let requestBodyString = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        NSLog("Request Body: %@", requestBodyString!)
        request.HTTPBody = data
    } catch ( _) {
        NSLog("Failed to encode json for Post Items")
    }
```

How do I fix it?

I want to have 2 arrays in my JSON:

1 - "accepted" 
2 - "rejected"

And 1 single object in my JSON:

1 - "address"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in this line `parameters["address"] = addressArray as [AnyObject]`. You are setting `Array` with `address` key instead of that you need to set dictionary. So create addressDic like this.

```
let adddressDic = ["city" : "Hong Kong",  "lng" : "114.162699999745", "country" : "Hong Kong", 
                   "street" : "Barker Road", "id" : "0", "label" : "Home", "lat" : "22.269837686727"]
```

Now set this `Dictionary` with `address` key

```
parameters["address"] = adddressDic
```

**Edit:** You need to also change the declaration of parameters like this.

```
var parameters = [String:AnyObject]()
```

Comment: Can't be done because of: var parameters = [String:[AnyObject]](). See my screenshot

Answer (score 0):

```
parameters["address"] = addressArray as [Any]
```

Here (in this line of code) you are assigning array instance. Create a JSON object (Dictionary) of 'addressArray' and then assign it to parameter["address"]

e.g.

```
var addresArray = [String : Any]()
```

//Store json values/information in it and then

```
parameters["address"] = addressArray as [String : Any]
```